# How can I style a cell frame with rounded corners?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

I'd like use rounded rectangles for my cell style, but I'm not sure if this is possible. Perhaps it can be faked with an image as a background for it?

Comment: `Framed` has the option `RoundingRadius`.  This is not for *cell frames* though, but it may lead the way to a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. One can set the four sides of the cell frame to various different styles using the undocumented option `CellFrameStyle` which you have to prefix with the `` System` `` context to get it to work (syntax coloring won't recognize it as a valid option):

```
CellPrint[
 TextCell[
   StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}], {200, 1000}], 
   "Text", 
   CellFrame -> True, 
   System`CellFrameStyle -> 
    { Directive[Red, Thickness[5] ], 
      Directive[Green, Thickness[10], Dashed ], 
      Directive[Blue, Thickness[5] , Dotted], 
      Directive[Gray, Thickness[5] , Dashing[{20, 3}]]
    }, 
   CellMargins -> {{100, 50}, {5, 5}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics].

The fact that you can specify it as four separate frame parts make me believe rounded corners are not possible. With sides specified separately I don't think an option like `RoundingRadius` would work.

Comment: On my system (v9 Linux), the `System` context is not required, and `Dashed` and `Dotted` do not seem to work the same as your example (but `Dashing` does). `CapForm` or `JoinForm` might be useful for producing rounding but also do not work.

Comment: @xerxes interesting. On Windows, using it without context, doesn't do anything. Upon inspection of the cell code (ctrl shift E) I see an extra $CellContext tagged to CellFrameStyle. Tagging it with System prevents this.

Answer (score 9):

You might work around the limitations of `CellFrame` by framing the content. `Framed` allows for a `RoundingRadius`.

```
CellPrint[
Framed[TextCell[
StringTake[
ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}], {200, 1000}], "Text", 
CellMargins -> {{100, 50}, {5, 5}}], RoundingRadius -> 15, 
FrameStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Szabolcs. I only noticed your comment after answering the question. Really.

Comment: You notice the artefacts this yields in the text?

Comment: Thanks.  Placing `Framed` around the `TextCell` seems to take care of it.

Comment: Much better. Though not really a cell frame as asked by the OP, I think this is the closest to what it would look like.

Comment: Yes but this won't work in a style sheet :/